# Board of honor in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an board of honors to a Minesweeper game. I'm using localstorage to save the user's name and his score. How can I save the Level that the user played? I want to do this so that I can printout a ranking board.

Edit:

```
function won()
{
    stop_timer();
    document.getElementById("tab").onclick=null;                 
    document.getElementById("tab").oncontextmenu=null;
    localStorage.setItem(""+time,""+user);
    honor();
    clearTable();
}
```

And I am printing the score like this:

```
function honor()
{
    document.getElementById("honor_mul").style.display="block";

        var container = document.getElementById("honor_mul");

        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute("class","test");
        table.setAttribute("id","table_rank");

        var tableRow = table.insertRow(0);
        var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(0);

        tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Rank"));
        container.appendChild(table);

        tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(1);
        tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Nome"));
        container.appendChild(table);

        tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(2);
        tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Score"));
        container.appendChild(table);    

    for( var i=1; i<=10; i++){
        {

            if(i<=localStorage.length)
            {
                var tableRow = table.insertRow(i);
                var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(0);
                tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
                container.appendChild(table);
                var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(1);
                tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i-1))));
                container.appendChild(table);
                var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(2);
                tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(localStorage.key(i-1)));
                var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell(3);
                tableCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem()));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to printout the top 10 scores for each level. 
Thanks

Comment: We need some code to help you.

Comment: *"How can I save the Level that the user played?"* The same way you store the name and score?

Comment: I updated the post with code.